# text method not working with ie's

Tags: jquery

I am getting some `XML` text information like this:

```
var timeZones = {
    chennai : 'getTime.php?lat=13.0833333&lan=80.2833333'
}

$.each(timeZones, function(key,value){
    $.get(value, function(response){
        var getResTime = $(response).find('localtime').text();
        //var getResSec =
        //day = getResTime.substring(12,2);
        //month = getResTime.substring(14,3);
        //year = getResTime.substring(17,3);

        alert(getResTime);

    }) 
})
```

But in Internet Explorer the `alert()` is not appearing. All other browsers are fine. Can anyhelp to get it to work in IE?

after i gone through with some of articles, i did changed my function in to like this, to get the result from IE,

```
 var timeZones = {
        chennai : 'getTime.php?lat=13.0833333&lan=80.2833333'
    }

$.each(timeZones, function(key,value){
                    $.get(value, function(data){
                      parseXml(data);
                      var myLocation = $(data).find('localtime').text();
                      alert(myLocation);
                    }) 
                })

                function parseXml(xml) {
                    if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
                        var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM"); 
                        xmlDoc.loadXML(xml);
                        xml = xmlDoc;
                    }   
                    return xml;
                }
```

now i am receving the data as xml, but i can't find the 'localtext' information from the data, only on ie's. rest of the browsers works fine. ( i am getting the alert), any wrong this i did?

suggestion pls..?

Comment: Try specifying the `xml` datatype. `}, 'xml');` at the end of the `$.get` call.

Comment: Also, make sure to use semi-colons at the end of your statements. `});`

Answer (score 0):

IE can't treat custom tags as valid DOM elements.

For IE, such thing: `<localtime>10:00</localtime>` is not valid DOM and the value can't be extracted by using the standard methods.

Most simple solution will be if you can change the XML format to use standard HTML, for example:

```
<div class="localtime">10:00</div>
```

Then change the code to:

```
var getResTime = $(response).find('.localtime').text();
```

And it should work fine on all browsers.

Comment: I am getting from a URL, while i am getting from URL, i am receiving as XML.. then how can i change the xml tree in to valide text tree?

Comment: What do you mean "getting from URL"? Can you post example?